# Ошибка загрузки .net assembly в mscorlib::_AppDomainPtr

Tags: c++, .net, clr

Здравствуйте!

Имеется код на c++ который успешно создаёт CLR в нативном процессе.
Сделал всё на основе "[C++ app hosts CLR 4 and invokes .NET assembly (CppHostCLR)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0)".

Всё прекрасно работает до момента загрузки нужных managed сборок:

```
_AppDomainPtr pDefaultAppDomain;
wchar_t* assembly = "example.dll"

_AssemblyPtr sAssembly = nullptr;
lastResult = pDefaultAppDomain->Load_2(assembly, &sAssembly);
if (FAILED(lastResult))
{
    DBG_W(L"Failed to load the assembly: %s (%#010x)", assembly, lastResult);
    return false;
}
```

Постоянно выдаёт ошибку `0x80131535 (COR_E_MARSHALDIRECTIVE)`
В гугле не нашёл документации, что может вызывать эту ошибку.

На этапе инициализации CLR ошибок нет, нужная dll 100% лежит по пути подгрузки.
Версии CLR совпадают (`v4.0.30319`)

**В чём причина и как исправить?**

*Спасибо.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эх, c++ вещь конечно хорошая, но заставляет документацию шерстить сильно.

Оказалось дело в инкапсуляции, `pDefaultAppDomain->Load_2` на вход просит `BSTR`
который инкапсулирует `WCHAR` (по этому никаких ошибок при компиляции):

```
typedef WCHAR OLECHAR;
typedef OLECHAR* BSTR;
typedef BSTR* LPBSTR;
```

Но им он не является [(доки)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The following code is incorrect: `BSTR MyBstr = L"I am a happy BSTR";`
>   This code builds (compiles and links) correctly, but it will not
>   function properly because the string does not have a length prefix. If
>   you use a debugger to examine the memory location of this variable,
>   you will not see a four-byte length prefix preceding the data string.

Правильно писать так:
`BSTR MyBstr = SysAllocString(L"I am a happy BSTR");`